# как узнать когда PathTransition передвижение объекта?

Tags: java, javafx

имеется код, передвигаю картинку по маршруту  path

```
 PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
 pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(time));
 pathTransition.setNode(imageView);
 pathTransition.setPath(path);
 pathTransition.setOrientation
      (PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
 pathTransition.play();
```

когда картинка придет в место назначения нужно вывести в консоль сообщение, как правильно это сделать? у меня есть время выполнения time засекать таймер и по прошествии времени выводить сообщение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод [setOnFinished(EventHandler)](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setOnFinished(javafx.event.EventHandler))

Например:

```
pathTransition.setOnFinished(System.out::println);
```

Comment: спасибо за быстрый ответ.